# Entity Framework 6 database first many to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am trying EF6 and trying to utilize a many to many relationship.

Using Database first here is my scripted out database.

```
CREATE TABLE [States] (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    Name varchar(50) not null,
    Abbreviation varchar(2) not null
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Departments (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    Name varchar(50),
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Role] (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    Name varchar(50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Employees (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    FirstName varchar(50),
    LastName varchar(50),
    Email varchar(255),
    DepartmentId int constraint fk_Department_Id foreign key references Departments(Id)
)

GO

CREATE TABLE AssignedRoles (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    EmployeeId int not null constraint fk_Employee_Id foreign key references Employees(Id),
    RoleId int not null constraint fk_Role_Id foreign key references [Role](Id),
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [Addresses] (
    Id int identity (1, 1) not null primary key,
    EmployeeId int not null,
    StreetAddress varchar(255),
    City varchar(55),
    StateId int not null,
    ZipCode varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Employee_Id_Address foreign key (EmployeeId) REFERENCES [Employees](Id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_State_Id foreign key (StateId) REFERENCES [States](Id)
)
GO
```

My Code:

```
public MicroOrmComparison.UI.Models.Employee Add(MicroOrmComparison.UI.Models.Employee employee)
{
    var employeeToInsert = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MicroOrmComparison.UI.Models.Employee, Employee>(employee);
    using (var db = new EmployeeDb())
    {
        db.Employees.AddOrUpdate(employeeToInsert);
        if (employeeToInsert.Addresses != null)
        {
            foreach (var address in employeeToInsert.Addresses)
            {
                db.Addresses.AddOrUpdate(address);
            }
        }
        if (employeeToInsert.Roles != null)
        {
            foreach (var role in employeeToInsert.Roles)
            {
                role.Employees.Add(employeeToInsert);
                db.Roles.AddOrUpdate(role);
                db.Employees.AddOrUpdate(employeeToInsert);
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        employee.Id = employeeToInsert.Id;
    }
    return employee;
}
```

Generated Employee from EF6 database first

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace EntityFramework.DataLayer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            this.Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
            this.Roles = new HashSet<Role>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DepartmentId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Generated Code for Role

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace EntityFramework.DataLayer
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Role
    {
        public Role()
        {
            this.Employees = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Guilty Test that is failing

```
        [Test]
    public void ShouldAddRolesToUser()
    {
        //Arrange
        var testUserId = InsertUserToBeModified();
        //Act
        var employee = _employeeRepository.GetFullEmployeeInfo(testUserId);
        employee.Roles.Add(new MicroOrmComparison.UI.Models.Role
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Supervisor"
        });
        _employeeRepository.Save(employee);
        //Assert
        var result = _employeeRepository.GetFullEmployeeInfo(testUserId);
        result.Roles.Count().Should().Be(1);
        result.Roles.First().Id.Should().Be(3);
        //Cleanup
        _employeeRepository.Remove(testUserId);
    }
```

The test says result.Roles.Count() is 0.

My issue is trying to add to the join table AssignedRoles. I have tried multiple inserts within the foreach within the role block but still no luck. I have searched within this site but still no luck. I have been working with Micro ORMs which is why the magic of the join table is blowing my mind. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have more code if needed, just let me know what code is unclear.

When I debug within the foreach loop its not adding to the join table. HELP

Comment: How did you try to insert into the table AssignedRoles?

Comment: That's what I'm hoping the foreach (var role in employeeToInsert.Roles) code is doing.
I'm new to Entity and am trying to add to db.Roles and db.Employees

Comment: I don't see in your code where you add to AssignedRoles table

Comment: I used code first to generate the model. I will update.

Comment: I used database first, but this is what I get when trying to edit AssingedRoles.
http://imgur.com/vEZZdB1

Comment: If the roles are already attached to employeeToInsert they should be inserted by EF, no need to add them explicitly.

Comment: exactly what I thought, but it's not working. I have the code above but no luck inserting into the assignedroles table. I query the table while running and it still has 0 records.

Comment: You should regenerate your edmx, is missing one entity http://imgur.com/qTsdM0i

Comment: I have regenerated but still no luck. Entity understands the relationship but won't insert.
http://imgur.com/SLTexLW

Comment: Did you run the .tt files by saving both of them, when generating the tables did you select your table or does the table exist in db? http://imgur.com/QzfNYXG . Restart your visual studio and try again.

Comment: Yes, tried to right click and say run custom tool on the higher diagram. And saved both .tt files, still same output. It knows that there is a table there because in the edmx.diagram file it has this line "<AssociationConnector Association="EmployeeDbModel.AssignedRoles" ManuallyRouted="false" >"
would that not prove that it understands the relationship and knows that the table exists?

Comment: Created a new "test" model and it shows assigned role, you were right just needed to clear out my old one and start again. Thanks so much for all your help!! Was still hoping there was a bit of magic that was going to happen but guess not :) @Mihai-Hantea you were a great help

Comment: Glad that worked for you. Sometimes it happens and best way is to try regenerating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

Your are missing the `AssignedRoles` table. I added the .edmx to my project and i have this entity `AssignedRole`. Try recreate your edmx.

Old Answer (Code First):

I just tried using your database structure and everything works fine.

```
EmployeeDbdb = new EmployeeDb();

  var empl = new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Test",
            LastName = "demo",
            Email = "aa@aaa.com"
        };

        var role = new Role
        {
            Name = "Role1"
        };

        db.Roles.AddOrUpdate(role);

        db.Employees.AddOrUpdate(empl);
        db.SaveChanges();


        db.AssignedRoles.AddOrUpdate(new AssignedRole
        {
            EmployeeId = empl.Id,
            RoleId = role.Id
        });

        db.SaveChanges();
```

OR:

```
EmployeeDbdb = new EmployeeDb();
var empl = new Employee
{
      FirstName = "Test",
      LastName = "demo",
      Email = "aa@aaa.com"
};

var role = new Role
{
    Name = "Role1"
};
db.Roles.AddOrUpdate(role);
db.Employees.AddOrUpdate(empl);
db.AssignedRoles.AddOrUpdate(new AssignedRole
{
      Role = role,
      Employee = empl
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: http://imgur.com/vEZZdB1

This is what I get when I try to do db.AssignedRoles, is there something I am missing? I thought entity was supposed to know the relationship between employee and role and that a specific call to AssignedRoles was not needed.

Comment: That's great.If the answer help fixing the problem can you please check the mark.

Comment: Yes, but how do you do it for database first?